# Latex bibliography not showing pages

Tags: natbib

Hello I am using Latex for my dissertation. I am using natbib for my references. I have added pages to my reference file but it does not appear in the bibliography when I compile it.

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{refagain.bib}
```

One of my references is

```
@book{rotman,
   author = {Joseph Rotman},
   edition = {4},
   isbn = {9781461241768},
   pages = {33, 89-124, 343-420},
   publisher = {Springer New York},
   title = {An Introduction to the Theory of Groups},
   year = {1999},
}
```

But it appears like this when I compile it

[5] Joseph Rotman. An Introduction to the Theory of Groups. Springer New York, 4
edition, 1999. ISBN 9781461241768.
52

I want pages to appear. How should I do this? Help please!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I don't think the pages key is meant to support a choice like that. Normally one cites the book, not the pages in it. Those can be referred to in each individual cite

Comment: For entries of type `@book`, the `pages` field is supposed to contain information about the total number of pages in the book. I actually know of no bibliography style that actually does anything with this field. For sure, the `plainnat` bib style does not. If your objective is to indicate the pages (or page ranges) from which you're citing, you should be writing `\cite[pp.~33, 89--124, 343--420]{rotman}`.